# Could no longer launches Firefox webdriver due to profile not completely cleaned out on Java

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, selenium-webdriver

Dear Selenium Webdriver Specialists,

I can no longer launches / instantiates the Firefox webdriver with the following error on line 4:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host localhost on port
7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
*** LOG addons.manager: Application has been upgraded
*** LOG addons.xpi: startup
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
*** LOG addons.xpi: Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\DOCUME~1
\george\LOCALS~1\Temp\anonymous464046490888820385webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Opening database
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Creating database schema
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-profile
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed in app-global
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on {20a82645-c095-46ed-80e3-08825760534b} installed in winreg-app- 
    global
*** LOG addons.xpi: Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Updating add-on states
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Writing add-ons list
*** LOG addons.manager: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Database closed
```

Note that webdriver could not take control of Firefox browser without crashing even though it is being opened up with nothing on it. i.e. not able to pass line 4.

Below is the code snippet which has worked in the past but crashed on line 4:

```
4.  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
5.  driver.get("http://www.abc.com/index.htm");
```

This issue has come about after having removed folder “E:\Mozilla Firefox Profile”  and Firefox profiles using command “firefox.exe –p” to access Firefox Profile Manager. However, it appears that Firefox Profile Manager also created many folders such as “C:\DOCUME~1\george\LOCALS~1\Temp\anonymous464046490888820385webdriver- profile\extensions\webdriver-staging” in my home folder which do not exist any longer.

As a result, I would need your assistance with resolving this issue on the following areas:

( i )  How to cleanly purge / remove all Firefox profile lookup / setup references and simply launches / instantiates generic (no profile) Firefox browser to successfully pass line 4.
( ii ) Noticed that the “system proxy setting” is set when Firefox is launched / opened by Firefox Webdriver, which suggests that it is still using profile from some where, but don’t know what & where. Yet, “no proxy” was set when opening Firefox manually.

A Firefox profile was originally setup so that Firebug & Firepath could be activated / included in browser when launched / invoked from within Selenium webdriver.

I am running Java 1.7.0_11, Selenium Webdriver 2.25.0 on Windows XP & 7 platforms.

Your assistance would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

George

Answer (score 1):

Your firefox version is upgraded which is not suppported by selenium. So downgrade to version 15 , (highest supported version as per my usage). It will work fine

You can download the required version of firefox from [here](http://download.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases)

To stop updating the firefox automatically, uninstall the Mozilla Maintenance Service ( in Windows) & in 
 Tools -> OPtions -> Advanced -> Updates Tab, disable updates checking for addons & firefox

Comment: Where can I find Firefox 15 to download? I couldn't find any sites despite searching around.

Comment: How to prevent Firefox from automatically updating to the latest version as well? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Found Firefox 15 at ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/15.0.1/win32/en-US/.

Comment: Found instruction on turning off automatic updates at http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/update-firefox-latest-version.